# How to allow metabase work with instance IP on Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, metabase

I am relatively new to AWS and metabase. I am trying to setup metabase with AWS EC2 instance. I have been able to spin up the instance and ssh into the server from my local linux machine. I also tried `http://localhost:3000/` and was able to access metabase homepage but now I want to use the EC2 instance public IP in this format: `http://ec2ip:3000/` but it is not going through.

I have followed the following steps:

- make sure the port 3000 is not blocked by the firewall
- Ensured port is open in the inbound rules
- Added port 3000 to my ufw locally.

But still I cannot access metabase home page from `http://ec2ip:3000/`. Please advise on how I can salvage the situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check steps mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-fix-connection-with-elastic-ip/) ? some of them are already checked by you but not all

Comment: Which "firewall" are you referring to in bullet #1? Which "inbound rules" are you referring to in bullet #2? Are both your client and the metabase server running Linux?

Comment: @amitd the link you attached is to show how I can connect to the instance but this is not the case because I have already connected to the instance. The issue is the link does now allow me access to metabase homepage using the ipv4 public address with the correspondong port

Comment: @jarmod The firewall in bullet 1 is my local machine firewall, I used this command to check: "sudo netstat -an | grep 3000 | grep -i listen". For bullet 2, the inbound rules I am referring to is the one attached to the instance in the security group - I also added a rule to my local using "sudo ufw allow 3000" and some other rules shown in this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04). Then for the last question, how do I confirm if they are running on Linux?

Comment: I'm confused. Your local machine is presumably the client and you're running the server on EC2. Why would your local machine be listening on port 3000? Also, you can use http://portquiz.net/ to test that your client can reach an internet server on a given port number, which will confirm that your client is not blocked by a firewall (on the client or in the client's network).

Comment: @jarmod my local machine is running on Linux and the EC2 instance is also running on Linux. I have just used the site you gave me to test and it confirms my client server is not blocked by a firewall. What can I do next?

Comment: Configure metabase to listen on 0.0.0.0, not localhost.